# How to find executing functions in between two function in C Programming

Tags: c, function, gdb

I know two functions func_1 and func_5, but there are some functions in between func_1 and func_5 for sure which I don't know what are those functions now my question is my program is hitting func_1 but not reaching to funct_5 somewhere between my program is getting crash when I ran gdb, but I didn't have any backtrace details since my program is getting stopped.

Now how can I know where and in which function it is getting crashed, I doubt in between those two functions func_1 and func_5 some function is creating that crash.

```
[Inferior 1 (process 23939) exited with code 01]
(gdb) bt
No stack.
```

Please can anyone tell me how to approach this?

Comment: Your question is very unclear, [edit] your question and show some code, even pseudo code.

Comment: If your program crashes while running under gdb, you should be able to get a stack trace that tells you where it crashed with the command `bt`.

Comment: I rolled back your last edit, the previous sentence was fine.

Comment: Why exactly is single-stepping not feasible?

Comment: bt shows "No stack" since the program is not running it is stopped. If I have bt details then there is no meaning to post this question.

Comment: OK, so your program exited properly somewhere between the call to `func_1` and the call to `func_5`, that's the reason you don't have a stack trace. You need to put some breakpoints at strategic places and check, we can't do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use gdb, `rbreak` and `backtrace` can help.

An example:

```
/* demo.c */
#include <stdio.h>

void fn1(void) { puts("Hello"); }
void fn2(void) { fn1(); }
void fn3(void) { fn2(); }
 
int main(void)
{
    fn3();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with `-g` flag on:

```
 gcc -std=c11 -Wall -pedantic -g -o demo demo.c
```

Create a script to automatize the task, call it `trace.gdb` (the name is not important) with the following contents:

```
set pagination off
rbreak demo.c:.
command
silent
backtrace 1
continue
end

run
```

Now run the command:

```
gdb -quiet -command=trace.gdb ./demo
```

The output is:

```
Reading symbols from ./demo...done.
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40053a: file demo.c, line 3.
void fn1(void);
Breakpoint 2 at 0x40054b: file demo.c, line 4.
void fn2(void);
Breakpoint 3 at 0x400556: file demo.c, line 5.
void fn3(void);
Breakpoint 4 at 0x400561: file demo.c, line 9.
int main(void);
#0  main () at demo.c:9
#0  fn3 () at demo.c:5
#0  fn2 () at demo.c:4
#0  fn1 () at demo.c:3
Hello
```